# Get Jenkins Workspace Number

Tags: jenkins

if I am running concurrent Jenkins jobs, eg,

```
TestPipeline
TestPipeline@2
TestPipeline@3
```

How do I get the value of @2, @3, etc? Is there an env variable, or do I have to back it out from the path? It isn't `EXECUTOR_NUMBER`, which doesn't always match.

Comment: You need to grep it out of `WORKSPACE` env variable. Something like `WorkspaceNum = sh(script: "echo ${WORKSPACE} | grep -oP '(?=@).*'", returnStdout: true).trim()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ben5556 told you in the comment, you have to parse the `WORKSPACE` environment variable.

For me, the best way to get the number (without using `sh`) is:

```
"@${env.WORKSPACE.split('@').last()}"
```

You can remove the `@` at the beginning of the string if you only want the number.